# HTML element not loaded on window.onload

Tags: javascript, html

HTML element throws null on window.onload.

Based on research, it should load.

```
function setData()
{
    document.getElementById("my").value = "set"; 
}

window.onload = setData();
```

Comment: It's a simple html with only this line in the body: <textarea id="my"></textarea>

Comment: One option is to place the script after `html` content.

Comment: Wondering why this wouldn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do the following the function `setData()` gets called immediately and does not wait for window load. The following line **executes** the right side function (`setData()`) and assigns itself as `window.onload` listener. However, we do not want to execute `setData()` at this stage. Rather we want `setData()` to be executed after the window is fully loaded.

```
window.onload = setData();
```

Instead, use `window.onload` in the following manner. This attaches the function as `window.onload` listener. When the window load finishes it executes the function body and that is actually the call to `setData()`.

```
window.onload = function () {
    setData();
}
```

The running code:

```html
<script>
    function setData() {
        document.getElementById("my").value = "set";
    }
    // document.addEventListener('readystatechange', event => {
    //     setData();
    // });
    window.onload = function () {
        setData();
    }

</script>

<textarea id="my"></textarea>
```

There are several other options:

- Call the function after `body` at the end (*executes after DOM elements are created*)
- Use `readystatechange` listener (*executes after the document is ready*)
- Use `jQuery $(document).ready()` (executed after the document is ready)

Here is another running example with `readystatechange` event listener:

```html
<script>
    function setData() {
        document.getElementById("my").value = "set";
    }
    document.addEventListener('readystatechange', event => {
        setData();
    });

</script>

<textarea id="my"></textarea>
```

Comment: "window.onload does not guarantee that the document is loaded fully." say whaaat?! Also, what's the purposeof readstatechange? what element's state is changing here? and to what?

Comment: @user2609410 I take that back. Modified the answer. I hope the explanation at the beginning clarifies the issue with the syntax you were using. Now, you have several options to make it work :)